# How to bypass TikTok's bot detection (selenium)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, bots, tiktok

Im currently trying to make a bot for tiktok thats just uploading a Video after one hour, then second hour, etc On multiple accounts at the same time, same video. But im currently stuck at the login Screen, it tells me "too many login attempts. Try again later" everytime selenium tries to login, the weird thing is that it worked 5 days ago and it worked perfectly fine without any errors, but now this happend.
Does anybody have any Idea why this happens?

Here's the code, if there is anything else you need to know feel free to ask:

```
import os
import time
from selenium_profiles.driver import driver as mydriver
from selenium_profiles.profiles import profiles
from selenium_profiles.scripts.driver_utils import actions
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from multiprocessing import Process
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium_stealth import stealth
import requests
import pyautogui
import random

wb = load_workbook("backend.xlsx")
ws = wb.active

accountCounter = 1

#These Variables are changeable

accountAmount = 1
hashtags = "#rich #money #luxury #millionaire #business #luxurylifestyle #lifestyle"
upload_cooldown = 30

######


mobile_emulation = {
    "deviceName": "Nokia N9"
}
s = Service("chromedriver_bypass.exe")
options = Options()

mydriver = mydriver()
profile = profiles.Android()


os.chdir("Vids")
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
options.add_argument("--profile-dictonary=Default")
options.add_experimental_option("mobileEmulation", mobile_emulation)
#user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS x86_64 8172.45.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.64 Safari/537.36"




def findPasswords():
    passwords = []
    for x in range(0, accountAmount):
        password = ws["B" + str(x + 2)].value
        passwords.append(password)
    return passwords



def findUsers():
    users = []
    for x in range(0, accountAmount):
        user = ws["A" + str(x + 2)].value
        users.append(user)
    return users


def createWebDrivers(accAmount):
    webDrivers = []
    for x in range(0,accAmount):
        #webDriver_x = webdriver.Chrome(service=s,options=options)
        webDriver_x = mydriver.start(profile, uc_driver=False)
        webDrivers.append(webDriver_x)
    return webDrivers

def createWaitDrivers(webDrivers):
    waitDrivers = []
    webDriverAmount = len(webDrivers)

    for x in range(0,webDriverAmount):
        waitDriver_x = WebDriverWait(webDrivers[x],7)
        waitDrivers.append(waitDriver_x)
    return waitDrivers

webDrivers = createWebDrivers(accountAmount)
waitDrivers = createWaitDrivers(webDrivers)
passwords = findPasswords()
users = findUsers()



def login(webDriver, waitDriver, user, password):

    #Fixing the Bot detection

    webDriver.get("https://www.tiktok.com/login/phone-or-email/email")
    #webDriver.get("https://bot.sannysoft.com/")
    time.sleep(random.uniform(1,3))
    y = input("Click away everything on the screen, if you have done so please write 'y'")
    if "y" in y:
        # username

        userBox = webDriver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/form/div[1]/input")
        userBoxLocation = actions.mid_location(userBox)

        action = actions.touch_action_chain()
        action.pointer_action.move_to_location(userBoxLocation["x"], userBoxLocation["y"])
        action.pointer_action.pointer_down()

        action.perform()
        time.sleep(random.uniform(1,3))

        for char in user:
            waitDriver.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "username"))).send_keys(char)
            time.sleep(random.uniform(.01, .1))

        time.sleep(10)

        # password

        waitDriver.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/form/div[2]/div/input"))).click()
        time.sleep(random.uniform(1,3))


        for char in password:
            waitDriver.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/form/div[2]/div/input"))).send_keys(char)
            time.sleep(random.uniform(.1, .2))

        time.sleep(15)

        waitDriver.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/form/button"))).click()
```

I tried changing the cdc_ variable in the chromedriver. I tried using undetected_selenium. I tried using selenium-stealth (currently in the code too), changing user agents etc. Also it is important to state that I use an excel worksheet to retrieve account data (via openpyxl)

Comment: Maybe try using [Selenium-Profiles](https://github.com/kaliiiiiiiiii/Selenium-Profiles) and don't manually overwrite the useragent after that. Selenium-stealth sometimes makes it worse.

Comment: I tried to use the Selenium-Profiles package and I tried using the profiles.Android() for the webdrivers (Its important to emulate a phone for my project) and it still gives me the error :/ I even tried openening the normal tiktok fy and following the page flow, not even that worked so I really have no Idea what could cause this

Comment: Mhh maybe you're logging-in and out to often//agressive? Or click on mobile, which should be touch? Or maybe try using random mouse-or-touch-patterns?

Comment: Logging in / out too aggressive is not the problem, works perfectly fine with the selenium browser open but manually logging in, if the code tries to it won't work thats why I think its something wit hthe code. How do you use touch instead of click? is it just "touch()"? and also how do I implement random mouse / touch patterns? Im sorry but im very new to this. Thx for the help tho!

Comment: [this](https://github.com/kaliiiiiiiiii/Selenium-Profiles#touch_actions) might help you with touch-actions.

Comment: I tried to replace the click with the touch_action but it doesnt work, I get this error:
`
line 108, in login
    userBox = webDriver.find_element((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/form/div[1]/input"))
`
and this:`
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: 'using' must be a string`

Comment: This is what I get when I only have on bracket: actions.mid_location() missing 1 required positional argument: 'element'

line 109, in login
    userBoxLocation = actions.mid_location(userBox)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: Can you maybe add the code you've tried to your question?

Comment: I updated it, do you have discord by any chance? If you want we can go on Discord and you can help me better, if oyu want.

Comment: I think the issue is: You need to initialize the actions using
`actions = actions(driver)`, and then build your action with `touch_action = actions.touch_action_chain()`

Comment: My discord user-name is `/╲/\╭(•‿•)╮/\╱\#3208`